# Excel File to CSV with some changes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert an Excel File to a CSV File. Therefore I found many basically Python scripts. But I have some challenges in the implementation of my own script. First of all the structure of my Excel file:

The first 10 rows and some columns are for informations, like:

```
Name:   Person last name(own Column)    Person first name(new column)
Place:  Country(own Column)
Date:   01.01.2019(own Column)
```

After this we have the information of the Values

```
Value1(U)   Value2(V)   Value3(W)
```

The Values are separated by a new column, the decimal places are separated by comma and not dot.

```
0,1 0,2 0,3
```

Now I want to write a small Python Script which can convert this into a CSV File with the following structure:

The informations of the first 10 rows shall stay as they are.

The informations of the values shall be separated by comma and not by new column.

```
Value1(U), Value2(V), Value3(W)
```

The decimal places of the values shall be separated by dot and not comma. The values shall be separated with a comma.

```
0.1, 0.2, 0.3
```

Does anyone have a Python script for this or have some ideas for me?

Many thanks in advance.

Andrew

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be careful to include all relevant information. Are the "values" in the 11th row and following in text or are they numbers? If they are numbers, does the comma in the visible cell come from the way the number is formatted in Excel? For a good answer, you should show us a sample small file, both the values and formulas typed into the cells and the way the cells appear. Also, have you done any work on this problem? Do you have a preferred library to get the Excel data out of the Excel file? Which Excel format is the file in--xlsx?

Comment: Are the commas as the decimal separators guaranteed to be the only commas in the numbers--no thousands separators?

Comment: The values are in the 11th row and are numbers. The commas are 100% decimal separators. I don't know how the program wrote the numbers in excel, but I see a comma as decimal separator. I worked on this problem but couldn't find a way. There is no library I prefer, just hope to solve the problem. The Excel format is now a CSV file (before it was .txt and after rename the File it was CSV, but the values are not comma separated, so it looks like typically Excel File). I could upload a small example file (not an original one) but how can I do it here?

Comment: If the "Excel file" is now a CSV file then it is not really an Excel file--you should just call it a CSV file. If that CSV was exported from Excel that is relevant, but you apparently say that is not the case here. And everything in a CSV file is text, even the "numbers" which are just representations of numbers in text. To confirm: in that input CSV file, the numbers are separated by spaces (not tabs)? More questions: Do you care if the first 10 rows are treated as one cell per line, since there apparently are spaces in the cells?

Comment: You can show us your input CSV by clicking the [edit text](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57132806/edit) at the bottom of your question, copying and pasting the top 15 rows or so of your input CSV file into your question, highlighting those lines, then clicking the `{}` button in your edit screen (or pressing 'CTRL+K`). This would answer some of my questions. Do that, then we will be much better placed to help you.